# Eclipse keeps freezing when I try to run this code for several minuts then shows NullPointerException

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, nullpointerexception, celllist

I have a program that should display a list of 4 x X elements. I am not that good with these lists so I did a lot of research combining several examples. I finally ended up making a class for it called `TabListCellRenderer`:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;


class TabListCellRenderer extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer{

    protected static Border m_noFocusBorder;
    protected FontMetrics m_fm = null;
    protected Insets m_insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
    protected int m_defaultTab = 50;
    protected int[] m_tabs = null;
    public TabListCellRenderer() {
        super();
        m_noFocusBorder = new EmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1);
        setOpaque(true);
        setBorder(m_noFocusBorder);
    }

    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list,Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus){
        setText(value.toString());
        setBackground(isSelected ? list.getSelectionBackground() : list.getBackground());
        setForeground(isSelected ? list.getSelectionForeground() : list.getForeground());
        setFont(list.getFont());
        setBorder((cellHasFocus) ? UIManager.getBorder("List.focusCellHighlightBorder") : m_noFocusBorder);
        return this;
    }

    public void setDefaultTab(int defaultTab) {
        m_defaultTab = defaultTab;
    }

    public int getDefaultTab() { 
        return m_defaultTab; 
    }

    public void setTabs(int[] tabs) {
        m_tabs = tabs; 
    }

    public int[] getTabs() { 
        return m_tabs; 
    }

    public int getTab(int index) {
        if (m_tabs == null)
            return m_defaultTab*index;
        int len = m_tabs.length;
        if (index>=0 && index<len)
            return m_tabs[index];
        return m_tabs[len-1] + m_defaultTab*(index-len+1);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        m_fm = g.getFontMetrics();
        g.setColor(getBackground());
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        getBorder().paintBorder(this, g, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.setColor(getForeground());
        g.setFont(getFont());
        m_insets = getInsets();
        int x = m_insets.left;
        int y = m_insets.top + m_fm.getAscent();
        StringTokenizer    st = new StringTokenizer(getText(), "\t");
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()){ 
            String sNext = st.nextToken();
            g.drawString(sNext, x, y);
            x += m_fm.stringWidth(sNext);
            if (!st.hasMoreTokens())
                break;
            int index = 0;
            while (x >= getTab(index))
                index++;
            x = getTab(index);
        }
    }
}
```

I then initialize the list by running the next piece of code on a JPanel:

```
TabListCellRenderer renderer = new TabListCellRenderer();
renderer.setTabs(new int[] {50, 200, 300});
listaAnimali.setCellRenderer(renderer);
```

If I run these 3 lines my Eclipse freezes for several minuts (3-5) then sais that the last of the 3 lines caused a `NullPointerException`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at classe_di_interfaccia.MyPanel.<init>(MyPanel.java:76)
    at classe_di_interfaccia.TestClass.main(TestClass.java:9)
```

Ass you can see there is no refrence to the class for the list. I tried working backwards in my head but as far as I can tell everything checks out.

I tried the debugging option on eclipse but that crashes the program. (no error code. it's just the windows system display like: "The program is not responding, do you want to close it?")

What have I missed? Is it a problem with eclipse? why is eclipse so slow?

Normaly it works fine (I stimulated a NullPointerException)

Using these 3 classes I can get it to bug out again (Using geany but it's much faster like 3 seconds)

Panel Example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Panel extends JPanel {

    private JPanel PanelOnPanel

    private JList listaAnimali;

    public PanelGrafica(){
        TabListCellRenderer renderer = new TabListCellRenderer();
        renderer.setTabs(new int[] {50, 200, 300});
        listaAnimali.setCellRenderer(renderer);

        panelList.add(listaAnimali);

    }
}
```

JFrame:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
  public MyFrame(){
    super(); 
    setBounds(100,100,350,600);
  }
  public MyFrame(String titolo){
    super(titolo);
    setBounds(100,100, 350,600);
  }
}
```

Class To Test:

```
import java.awt.*; 
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

public class Test{ 

    public static void main(String[] v){ 

    JFrame f = new MyFrame("Una Mensola Automatico"); 

    Container c = f.getContentPane(); 

    JPanel panel = new PanelGrafica();

    f.setResizable(false);

    f.show(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: What is this one: listaAnimali.setCellRenderer(renderer);

Comment: it's line 76: the one that makes the error. It's used to indicate to the list how many cells it has I believe (I got this code from the internet but I hav red all the info there is before I got here)

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson here you go I have a few testclasses up for you

Comment: What is at the source line 76 in MyPanel.java? Identified as source for the NPE here `at classe_di_interfaccia.MyPanel.<init>(MyPanel.java:76)`. Your posted class `Panel` seems not to be the same as `MyPanel`. Because `Panel.java` contains a constructor for class `PanelGrafica`. As Andrew said post code which demonstrates your problem.

Comment: An MCVE should make it very easy for people to test, so it should need only one copy/paste. To achieve that, copy the `Panel` & `MyFrame` source into the end of the one with `main` method, demote those classes from `public` to default access & resolve the imports, then get a new stack trace for the MCVE.